# Android IABv3 getSkuDetails not returning Sku Details

Tags: android, android-billing

I am currently battling with Android Iab v3.

I have previously been using the IabHelper class from Google to display available products with success. However, today it is no longer returning me anything.

The content of the querySku field passed to the getSkuDetails function of the IInAppBillingService in the IabHelper class is:

> Bundle[{ITEM_ID_LIST=[com.app.android.credits.10,
>   com.app.android.credits.25, com.app.android.credits.50]}]

What I get back in the bundle it return is:

> Bundle[{DETAILS_LIST=[], RESPONSE_CODE=0}]

Since the time it has worked and now I have not altered the IabHelper code at all along with the code that displays the products. The important bit of code being:

```
private void getItemsForSale()
{
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    skuList.add(getResources().getString(R.string.ten_credits_product_id));
    skuList.add(getResources().getString(R.string.twenty_credits_product_id));
    skuList.add(getResources().getString(R.string.fifty_credits_product_id));

    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, this);
}

@Override
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv)
{
    if(result.isFailure())
    {
         Log.d("DEBUG", "Error Inventory Query: " + result);
         AppMsg.makeText(BuyCreditsActivity.this, R.string.sorry_something_went_wrong, AppMsg.STYLE_ALERT).show();  
    }
    else
    {
         // Code here queries the inv object returned which has a blank array
    }
}
```

This is why I am so confused.

Does anyone have any idea as to what external factor might have caused this to start not returning any product details?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing. It used to work, now it doesn't, and I haven't changed anything related to iab. I did upgrade my adt bundle, but IInAppBillingService.aidl is unchanged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm getting the same empty bundle since yesterday. This question is not the same thing, but it was asked recently, and seems to be related: [Android inventory.getSkuDetails() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914789/android-inventory-getskudetails-returning-null)

 (I have experienced this one too about 2 weeks ago)

First answer states: 
"they say they have made changes which requires the apk to be published before adding in app purchases they recommend uploading the apk to alpha testing channel and published (not in draft mode)."

I will try this, perhaps it solves the problem.

**Update:** I published the app, but the developer console wrote that the modifications does not take effect immediately. After some hours the problem existed, but today it works well.

Comment: have this issue on Samsung only.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem. In my case the following worked:

1. Make sure it's actually *published* in alpha, beta, or production.
   If it appears, for example, as "Draft in Alpha" or beta then you
   haven't published in. Publishing means that you also need to upload
   the minimum required assets for Google Play, descriptions, content
   ratings, etc (See the APK, Store Listing, and Content Rating tabs in
   the developer console).
2. At least for alpha and beta testing, there is a list of testers that
   you must create and add each tester's email. Look for the "Manage
   Testers" section in the Alpha Testing or Beta Testing tab.
3. Each tester must also accept to be a tester. There is an opt-in URL
   link which you must send to your testers, and they must click on the
   link and accepts the conditions.
4. After all that is done, you still have to wait about 1 hour before
   the purchase details start to appear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does that mean, you won't be able to test in-app purchases in debug mode? The Sku details would only appear if you download and install the app from the Play Store (from the Opt-in URL)?

Comment: you can always build a release version from android studio and set `debuggable true` for your build type release  - and make sure your building the same exact one you uploaded to the play store